# How to get the status of an Webview from an activity?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm very new to android.

I have a `WebView` opened inside an activity named `Cards`, something like this:

```
 WebView webview = new WebView(this);
 setContentView(webview);
 webview.loadUrl("myurl")
```

This is opening a `WebView` as it is expected. But what I really what is to monitor the web page that is been loaded from this url.

Since the page that is opening is of payment page, when the user done the payment I need to know whether he went to success page or failure page.

If its success then I need to take him to other activity and so.

What I thought is to get the title of the webpage using `getTitle()` method(kind of *pooling*). But I want to know are there any other ways to achieve it?

How do I monitor the webpage? Are there any best practices for it? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement an extension to WebViewClient and then use webview.setWebViewClient to register it you get notified of various changes in the webview.  You can also implement the ChromeClient but it is less useful for your purposes.

In particular onPageFinished or shouldOverrideURLLoading will be useful in this case (depending on whether you want to detect after the fact or intercept).